# Add a Comment on/off option in Screen Options for Comments?

Tags: comments

In the Wordpress dashboard, I want to be able to add the option to turn off the Comment column. Can I do that via functions.php? I found a plugin that does a lot of things, but since I need this one small thing, I thought to keep it light.

I really hope someone knows this. Thanks!

[image: comments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you should filter the `manage_edit-comments_columns` [filter](http://hookr.io/filters/manage_edit_comments_columns/) to remove the core comment column, and add a custom comment column so the checkbox shows up in the screen options tab.

For the output of comments, you would then need to get `comment_content` from the `comment` for display output in the `manage_comments_custom_column` [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_comments_custom_column/).

This is an example of the above code:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', function( $columns ) {

    // Remove core comment column.
    unset( $columns['comment'] );

    // Custom "Comment" column to add to screen options and output.
    $custom_column = [ 'WPSE356451_add_comment' => 'Comment' ];
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 2, true ) + $custom_column + array_slice( $columns, 2, NULL, true );

    return $columns;
} );

add_action( 'manage_comments_custom_column', function( $column, $comment_ID ) {
    global $comment;

    // Check for custom comment column and handle output.
    if ( 'WPSE356451_add_comment' === $column ) {
        echo $comment->comment_content;
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

Here's a [gist for the code above](https://gist.github.com/timelsass/cb4ed1497f562ff5b716fceb4e6b2ec0), and a direct [plugin .zip for download](https://gist.github.com/timelsass/cb4ed1497f562ff5b716fceb4e6b2ec0/archive/e86d78cb6834ffbaae0d01df9a5ee16994970644.zip).

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! The code did the trick!